# why doesn't this work -> https://jsfiddle.net/hc8g901k/

Tags: javascript

what is wrong there???? i dont get it

https://jsfiddle.net/hc8g901k/

HTML

```
<a class=btn onclick='red'></a><a id="btn" class=btn onclick='red'></a>
```

CSS

```
   .btn {
  background-color:#00cc00;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:2px ;
```

JS

```
function red() {
document.getEementById("btn").style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you're seeing? Please don't just drop code and ask "what's wrong". *Describe* what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issue,

1. Issue with JSFiddle: JsFiddle declares are variable in local scope and hence cannot find the method. It should work on your page/website.
2. There is a typo: getEementById missing `l`.
3. Your object is in document so just write `document.getElementById()`

This works. https://jsfiddle.net/hc8g901k/5/